# Hexo excerpt <!-- more --> not working after update

Tags: javascript, node.js, hexo

I just updated my Hexo blog to the latest version. After updating, the `<!-- more -->` tag seems to stop working. Instead of showing an excerpt on the homepage it just shows all the content. I am using the Next theme.

I found an issue on the hexo github: https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/pull/1519

Which looks like the problem I am having. I tried to edit this file locally but nothing happens, still not working.

Is there are npm cache or something I need to clear when I edit a package in node_modules directly?

Thanks

Comment: The theme that you use can be incompatible with the new version of Hexo? What theme do you use?

Comment: Hi, I am using the Next theme: https://github.com/iissnan/hexo-theme-next

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to remove the `node_modules` directory and re-run `npm install`?

Temporarily solution :
You have to downgrade to a stable version of Hexo by setting `"hexo": "hexo.stable.version"` in your `package.json`  or you can add your own filter to do the job in the `scripts` folder of your theme. This file will be using at the startup of Hexo. Name the file : excerpt.js. The full path will : your-blog/themes/next/scripts/excerpt.js

```
var rExcerpt = /<!-- ?more ?-->/;

hexo.extend.filter.register('after_post_render', function(data) {
    var content = data.content;

    if (rExcerpt.test(content)){
        data.content = content.replace(rExcerpt, function(match, index){
            data.excerpt = content.substring(0, index).trim();
            data.more = content.substring(index + match.length).trim();

            return '<a id="more"></a>';
        });
    } else {
        data.excerpt = '';
        data.more = content;
    }
});
```

It should work.

Comment: Thanks. I tried deleting the node_modules folder and reinstall but that didn't work. The temporarily solution works! Thanks

Comment: Really strange, the code worked fine . . after I shutdown hexo server and tried again it returned to the old state as if the excerpt.js is not being read anymore.

Comment: yes that's strange. To see if the script is executed : add a console.log in the `excerpt.js` script

Comment: Hi, I added a console log in the excerpt.js file. When I run hexo server I see that the log is being printed out.